# Javascript canvas.toDataURL not working like Expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I want to preface that this is my first project using pure js, lol.

So I am in the process of creating a chrome extension for chromeOS that changes the wallpaper daily to AI generated art. I was doing this in steps - meaning that I first got working the web-scraper to get the newest art image from Nightcafe (going to be user defined once I build out the extension). I then got working the ability to run this on a timer to change the wallpaper. The only fundamental issue is the image itself. These images are randomly generated to match different screen size. But, it doesn't look right because of the image format. I want to convert the image into a 16:9 format. I cannot find any usable public apis that don't require a key (because I want to keep the repository on github), so I settled on mimicking [this](https://photo16x9.com/) website with the blur feature. I really like the way the final image looks on my desktop. Its also perfect because the website just uses pure js to achieve the goal. I stripped the necessary info and it looks like it is just using a canvas to edit the image and then download it. So, I implemented it in my code like this:

Background.js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


// chrome.alarms.create(
//   'test',
//   {delayInMinutes: 1, periodInMinutes: 1},
// );

function fillBlur(link) {


  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

  img.onload = function(){

    var dx = 0;
    var dy = 0;

    var calculatedHeight = Math.round((img.width / 16) * 9);
    var calculatedWidth = Math.round((img.height / 9) * 16);


    //Need to pad above and below
    if (calculatedHeight > img.height) {
        dy = Math.round((calculatedHeight - img.height) / 2);
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = calculatedHeight;
    } else {
        dx = Math.round((calculatedWidth - img.width) / 2);
        canvas.width = calculatedWidth;
        canvas.height = img.height;
    }


    // 


    // ctx.drawImage(img, dx, dy, img.width, img.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, dx, dy, img.width, img.height);

    // ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    // ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // img.style.display = 'block';
    // canvas.style.display = 'none';
    // // ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
  img.src = link;


  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
  }, 5000);
  //Don't want checkered background here...

  // ctx.filter = 'blur(15px)';

}

function getArtLink(link)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.open("GET", link, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    var r = xmlHttp.responseText;
    var pos = r.indexOf("og:image") + 19;
    var posEnd = r.indexOf('"/><meta property="og:image:alt"') -1;
    return r.substring(pos, posEnd);
}

// chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
//   if (alarm.name === "test") {

//     chrome.wallpaper.setWallpaper(
//       {
//         'url': fillBlur(getArt('https://creator.nightcafe.studio/explore?q=new')),
//        'layout': 'CENTER_CROPPED',
//         'filename': 'test_wallpaper'
//       },
//       function() {}
//     );
//   }
// });

function create(){
  chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('background.html')});
}

function test(){

    var link = 'https://creator.nightcafe.studio/explore?q=new';
    fillBlur(getArtLink(link));


    


}
```

background.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
        <script src="background.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

manifest.json just in case

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Mason Test App",
    "description": "Mason Test App 2",
    "version": "1.1",
    "icons": {
    "128": "128.ico"
    },
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html",
        "persistent": false
      },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "alarms",
        "wallpaper",
        "*://creator.nightcafe.studio/*"
      ]

      
    }
```

So the issue is that console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/png')) only loads the first third of the image. The rest of the image is just white. However, if I go to background.html in the developer console, the image is fully loaded onto the canvas including the infill of black; I just can't get a link that fully represents the image.

It seems like its some kind of hard limit. The ai art generates all kinds of formats. If the image thats generated is skinny, the image loads a little over halfway. If the image thats generated is wide, it only loads 1/5th of the image before it turns white. the way I am looking at the link is using console.log() and just pasting the uri in my browser. It just seems like there is a hard limit here but I don't know too much about js to properly troubleshoot the issue and 1 full day of googling has come up with nothing.

I have tried adding delays everywhere to make sure that all process are completed before the link is generated. I update the extension in chrome and then go to the developer console for that extension and execute create(). This creates the tab and then I go into the developer console for that tab and execute test(). This renders the canvas and the canvas shows up fine when rendered there. I just can't get a valid uri using canvas.toDataURL

Comment: console.log only shows a part of the text if it's long. There may be a link to copy the entire text. Also, see what happens if you actually display the result in your extension directly.

Comment: @wOxxOm So I did some testing after posting and it looks like if I use the uri, provided by the toDataURL function, to download the image...I get the full image. So it does seem like you are right where console.log has a limit on itself. Im troubleshooting a problem that doesn't exist, lmao. Thanks for your help!